# parse error when trying get request with ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, jsonp

I have seen the previous questions asked by others in stack overflow.but did'nt work for me.Iam getting the data in json when seen in the network panel,but

```
var jsonData = {
    "name": fbUsername, 
    "email": fbEmail 
};
console.log(jsonData);

$.ajax({
    type: "get",
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: jsonData,
    jsonp: false,
    jsonCallback: 'jsonCallback',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    crossDomain: true,
    headers: { "api_key": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" },
    url: "https://xaxxxxxxxxxx/prod/users",
    success: function(res) {
        alert("success!");
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(textStatus);
    }
});  

function jsonCallback(results){
    alert(results);
}
```

> PARSE ERROR

I am getting the response in JSON

```
['name1','name2']
```

although the response is JSON and why it is coming an parse error?

Comment: I'm confused. You say you're getting the response as an array and a 'parse error'?

Comment: why you setting jsonp if you return just json?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan yes.is that because of it it thinking the response as json.but it got an array?

Comment: @Maxx because cors problem

Comment: @kevin if your code waits jsonp then return jsonp not just json array

Comment: @Maxx I cannot change the response to jsonp.(as the api returns only json).so any alternamtive

Comment: your server output should be `jsonCallback(["name1","name2"])`

Comment: can you please elaborate or write in code snippet.

Comment: @kevin then you can't use jsonp. in this case request this api from your server and then redirect to your client

Comment: If your server returns JSON then you cannot use JSONP - they're not interchangeable. If you're doing that to try and avoid CORS issues then there is nothing you can do. The API has not been set up to allow access via JS code. You need to make the request server-side instead.

Comment: @Maxx I cant I have to use client side.`function jsonCallBack()` doesn't work?

Comment: @kevin you can't convert json response to jsonp response without server access. `jsonCallback` function must be inside server response, not inside your code